# Stopping the method until another execution finished?

Tags: java

I have a for loop which adds 50,000 objects to ArrayList like shown below, so it takes longer time to execute.

```
public List<GoogleFeedEntry> getEntries(Iterator it) {
    GoogleFeedUtil gfu = new GoogleFeedUtil(host, prefix, domain, serverName);
    List<GoogleFeedEntry> entry = new ArrayList<GoogleFeedEntry>();
    GoogleFeedEntry gfe;
    GoogleFeedEntryShipping shipping;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        gfe = new GoogleFeedEntry();
        shipping = new GoogleFeedEntryShipping();
        ProductBO product = (ProductBO) it.next();

        entry.add(gfe);
    }
    return entry;
}
```

After this method I am calling another method something like

```
public void doSomething(){
         //some code here
}
```

I am calling these two methods inside another method. IF i put limited number of Objects to list then it is working with out any problem. In case of 50,000 objects it is throwing following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Maximum open cursors exceeded ORA-01000
```

I felt this is nothing to do with oracle(If i am correct). ofcourse i am loading all the objects from the database.

When i set the break point  at the first method then it is working fine.

How can I stop second method until the first method executes?

What could be the reason?

Comment: Your error seems pretty straightforward: you do not close cursors in your oracle DB. Besides: why are you creatig a new shiping each iteration? What do you get the product for? It's unused.

Comment: @Dariusz I am creating shipping for each iteration because every object has its own shipping details. I am using it all code is not posted

Comment: unless you are doing something special the second method is not running until the first method returns

Comment: @Nathan Hughes I am riveting the BOS from sql query  closing and opening of database connections is taken care by frame work. i have nothing to do with them

Comment: If you are getting an Oracle error it has something to do with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this method in another thread and stop him using `wait()` and run him later using `notify()` method.